# Core Data Fetch is running slow

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know this questions pops up a good bit but I have not found a solution for my particular problem.

Ok so it takes approximately 6 seconds to fetch 25 objects from my model. There are 19 columns on this object with one being an image. I use a FetchedResultsController to fetch. The data is sorted into sections and displayed using a UITableViewController. This issue is fairly new to my app. When I first programmed this I had no significant lag on the fetch until I got up to 200 objects. With that being said I have my batch size set to 25.

I noticed that in both the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection both trigger an SQL statement when I pass them my FRC like so:

```
[[[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];

[[self.frc sections] count];
```

Is this not the right way to call for TableView? Why would each of these statements take 2.5 seconds? Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: It's probably a problem with trying to update your table off the main thread. If you're calling reloadData, try wrapping it in a dispatch_async() to the main queue.

Comment: Try just the reloadData first.

Comment: I mean that helps with not blocking the user interface but it still takes 6 seconds to fetch about 20 objects which just seems ridiculously long for such a small data set.

Comment: Try fetching without the images, or at least make sure the images empty and see if there is a performance improvement.

Comment: Step one, run Instruments -> Time Profiler.  What does that tell you? If you are unfamiliar with Time Profiler, post the profile as part of this question and I will be happy to take a look at it for you.

Comment: Ok. I ran a Time Profile. What do I need to upload to help?